# EventKit last event of calendar

Tags: ios, objective-c, eventkit

I'm making an app in which I sync certain events to a calendar on iPhone.

The problem is, I have no way of telling which events were altered/removed/...
So **I need to remove all the events between today and the end date of the last event of the calendar** before 'syncing' (read inserting) the new events.

As far as I've seen, the only way to do an action on multiple events at once, is by using [enumerateEventsMatchingPredicate:usingBlock:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventKit/Reference/EKEventStoreClassRef/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/EKEventStore/enumerateEventsMatchingPredicate:usingBlock:) and [predicateForEventsWithStartDate:endDate:calendars:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventKit/Reference/EKEventStoreClassRef/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/EKEventStore/predicateForEventsWithStartDate:endDate:calendars:)

But for this I need a specific end date. (and thus, the end date of the last event in my calendar)

I could always save the event identifier of the last event I insert into this calendar, but I would rather not do this:
If the user uninstalls my app and installs it again later, I don't have the last event identifier anymore. (given that (s)he didn't remove the calendar manually of course)

I could just remove the calendar every time I need to sync the calendar, but then I would lose all passed events.

Any ideas or tips are much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

For your comment on :

> I can't seem to find any way to fetch all the events of a calendar.

Actually you can fetch all the events from calendar :

```
NSDate *start = ...
NSDate *finish = ...

// use Dictionary for remove duplicates produced by events covered more one year segment
NSMutableDictionary *eventsDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:1024];

NSDate* currentStart = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:0 sinceDate:start];

int seconds_in_year = 60*60*24*365;

// enumerate events by one year segment because iOS do not support predicate longer than 4 year !
while ([currentStart compare:finish] == NSOrderedAscending) {

    NSDate* currentFinish = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:seconds_in_year sinceDate:currentStart];

    if ([currentFinish compare:finish] == NSOrderedDescending) {
        currentFinish = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:0 sinceDate:finish];
    }
    NSPredicate *predicate = [eventStore predicateForEventsWithStartDate:currentStart endDate:currentFinish calendars:nil];
    [eventStore enumerateEventsMatchingPredicate:predicate
                                      usingBlock:^(EKEvent *event, BOOL *stop) {

                                          if (event) {
                                              [eventsDict setObject:event forKey:event.eventIdentifier];
                                          }

                                      }];       
    currentStart = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:(seconds_in_year + 1) sinceDate:currentStart];

}

NSArray *events = [eventsDict allValues];
```

Comment: but thats for a fixed end date, no?

Comment: you can change the date and call it whenever you need

Comment: Yes, but then I still need to supply an end date, which is exactly the one thing I don't know. I don't really need the last event, I need the end date of that event. If I would use this, I would probably be better of to just put some random date in the future as the end date for my predicate.

Comment: sorry that I couldn't get you. Do you mean, you want to call this method by sending different end dates?

Comment: what do you mean by end date of that event? DO you want to get the last date,if the event exists on more than one day?

Comment: I just need to be able to determine the end date of the last event of a given calendar. If there is no other option than what you supplied here, then I think my best option is to just use `now + 1 year` as my end date.